# Why is this website loading in the browser but gives a 503 error in aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp, http-status-code-503

I am trying to load an RSS feed via aiohttp

```
from datetime import datetime
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import os

request_headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0",  # noqa: B950
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",  # noqa: B950
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
}

async def fetch_url(url, save_to_file=False):
    try:
        print('loading...', url)
        timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=30)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=timeout) as session:
            async with session.get(url, headers=request_headers, raise_for_status=True, ssl=False) as response:
                text = await response.text('utf-8')
                print('success...', url)
                if save_to_file:
                    current_timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S')
                    name_part = urlparse(url).netloc
                    file_name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'extras', 'feeds', current_timestamp, name_part)
                    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(file_name), exist_ok=True)
                    with open(file_name, 'w+') as f:
                        f.write(text)
                return (url, response.status, len(text))
    except Exception as e:
        print('failure...', url, e)
        return (url, -1)

async def main(urls, save_to_file):
    tasks=[fetch_url(url, save_to_file=save_to_file) for url in urls]
    results=await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    return results

urls = ['https://coinfomania.com/feed/']

asyncio.run(main(urls, False))
```

When I open this url in Chrome browser, it seems to load the data but gives me a 503 error everytime via aiohttp. Can someone kindly tell me how to fix this?

Just for the record I have a cron job that loads this url every 2 mins

Comment: its protected by cloudflare

Comment: @Alexander ok so how do you load that rss in aiohttp and also isnt the whole purpose of publishing a feed so that readers can load it

Comment: I looked at their main website and I don't see them advertise an rss feed anywhere on it.  Maybe it is just meant for internal use.  I am just guessing though.  You might be able to get the feed if you are able to duplicate the cookies that cloudflare generates during it's authentication process.